# ACID interrelationship

Tags: database, acid

Transaction properties and their interrelationship?
 The interrelationship among these attributes. how they are dependent on each other, that is, what could happen to other properties if one is not satisfied during the execution of concurrent transactions.

Comment: Please restructure your question to make it more clear. Thank you.

Comment: There are four transaction properties, ACID(Atomicity Consistency Isolation and Durability) is there an interrelationship between these? if so what is it? If one the properties are not satisfied in a transaction, what will happen?